# WebApi + OData: limit maximum results

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a WebAPI controller that takes an `ODataOptions` parameter.

I want to make sure the user can't download the whole database in one swoop.
So I validated the `options` object:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<ViewModel> options)
{ 

    var oDataValidationSettings = new ODataValidationSettings
    {
        MaxTop = 100
    }
    try 
    {
        options.Validate(oDataValidationSettings);
    } 
    catch (ODataException ex)
    {
        return BadRequest("OData query validation failed: " + ex.Message);
    }
    //return results
}
```

This works great for calls like

```
http://host/api/controller?$filter=...&$top=1000
```

This returns the expected validation error message.

But it is trivially easy to circumvent by simply making a request to:

```
http://host/api/controller?
```

No `$top`, no nothing. **This in effect returns the whole table!**
The validator is not triggered if the `$top` parameter is not specified at all.

I could append a `.Take(100)` when constructing the query from the oData options, but it seems hacky.

Is there any better way to deal with a missing `$top`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use PageSize which will limit the number of entity been returned.
Refer to this example for how to use it.
https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/ODataPagingSample

Comment: 404 on that link